# How to search parts of a string in a dictionary key in python and replace the matched string with dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, standardization

I have a database table column address and want to search for abbreviations (Address like STE,ST,AVE,BVLD, etc., and replace them all  State, Street Avenue, etc.). I have the Abbreviation and Long form in a table in Snowflake and also a table having an address in the table. I have implemented the logic using the Snowflake connector to bring the data into dataframes and populate the Abbreviations table into a dictionary inside python so that lookup is faster.

Please let me know where I am missing the code. I am getting an str error when trying to use find, contains, etc functions

```py
    ADD_ABBREVIATIONS={};

    #print(df)
    sql_abbreviations="SELECT ABBRVTN_SHRT_CD,ABBRVTN_DESCRIPTION FROM 
                       DATAANALYTICS.PUBLIC.ADDRESS_STANDARDIZATION"
    df1=pd.read_sql(sql_abbreviations,engine)
    #print(df1)
    ADD_ABBREVIATIONS=df1.to_dict(orient="records");
    #print(ADD_ABBREVIATIONS)
    sql_final_query=     "SELECT DISTINCT 
CONSUMER_NUMBER,CONSUMER_SHPPNG_FNAME,CONSUMER_SHPPNG_LNAME,IFNULL(UPPER(TRIM(CONSUMER_SHPPNG_ADDRESSL1)),' ') AS Consumer_Add1,IFNULL(UPPER(TRIM(CONSUMER_SHPPNG_ADDRESSL2)),' ') AS Consumer_Add2 FROM ( SELECT CUSTOMER_NUMBER AS CONSUMER_NUMBER,SHIPPING_FIRSTNAME AS CONSUMER_SHPPNG_FNAME,SHIPPING_LASTNAME AS CONSUMER_SHPPNG_LNAME, CASE SHIPPING_ADDRESS_LINE1 WHEN NULL THEN 'Unknown' WHEN '' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE SHIPPING_ADDRESS_LINE1 END AS CONSUMER_SHPPNG_ADDRESSL1, CASE SHIPPING_ADDRESS_LINE2 WHEN NULL THEN 'Unknown' WHEN '' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE SHIPPING_ADDRESS_LINE2 END AS CONSUMER_SHPPNG_ADDRESSL2 FROM DATAANALYTICS.PUBLIC.LNDG_WORLDPANTRY                               ) X ORDER BY CONSUMER_NUMBER ASC"
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_final_query,engine)
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(row[3])
         CONSUM_ADD1=row[3]
    #print(CONSUM_ADD1)
          print(ADD_ABBREVIATIONS)

    for key, value in ADD_ABBREVIATIONS:
        print(ADD_ABBREVIATIONS)
        print(ADD_ABBREVIATIONS.getitem(key))
        new_varkey = key[0]
        new_varval = value[0]
        print(new_varkey)
        if CONSUM_ADD1.find(new_varkey):
           print("No key is here!")
        else:
           print("Found key in the string.")
    #for key, value in ADD_ABBREVIATIONS[0].items():
    #    for v in range(len(value)):
            #print(key)
            #print(v)
            #if ADD_ABBREVIATIONS[0].items().find(row[3]) == -1:
            #    print("No key is here!")
            #else:
                #print("Found key in the string.")
            #contain = CONSUM_ADD1[(CONSUM_ADD1.str.contains(key[k]))]
            #if not contain.empty:
             #  print(k)
        if row.items('Consumer_Add1').isin(ADD_ABBREVIATIONS.key()):
        {
          print('Key Exist')
        }
        else:
          {
            print('Key does not Exist')
          }
```

Comment: Dont post code as images, post as text

Comment: It can hard too see, can you post the code se we can easily point out a mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.